# Shiny input as default value for another input

Tags: r, if-statement, input, shiny, conditional-statements

Is it possible to have the product from two inputs as a default value for another input?

Even, more complex, is it possible to include an if cycle in the computation?

Example:

```
library(shiny) 

ui <- fluidPage(
numericInput("factor","Factor:")
numericInput("delta","Delta:"),
numericInput("size","Size:"),
numericInput("result","result:",value = input$delta*input$size)
)
```

Advanced:

I would like to have `input$delta*input$size` multiplied for `input$factor` if `input$factor` is different than 100.

I tried to pass the value in the server by connecting it to an output and then having the latest as input but it did not work (I would say obviously).

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make one input dependent on the value of another, you need to specify it in the server. I usually render the result using `uiOutput()` and `renderUI`

```
library(shiny) 


shiny::shinyApp(ui = fluidPage(
  numericInput("factor","Factor:", 1),
  numericInput("delta","Delta:", 1),
  numericInput("size","Size:", 1),
  uiOutput('res')
  
), server = function(input, output){
  output$res <- renderUI({
    numericInput("result","result:",value = input$delta*input$size)
  })
})
```

Comment: Actually, I would need `output$res` to be available for changes from the user (so it should be another input and not an output). As I said in the comment before, I am looking to have `input$delta*input$size` as default value in the input `result`

Comment: That reprex should run, and does what you describe -- the `uiOutput` will render as a numeric input with the id `result`.

Comment: You use `uiOutput` in a variety of situations, but one is your use case where inputs need to be dynamic. Essentially everything that is dynamic in a Shiny app must be defined in a server function, so we create the needed UI elements using `uiOutput` in the ui function and `renderUI` in the server function. You can interact with it as you would with any other input.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation clarified everything. Truly appreciate!

Comment: last question on this before closing the topic, how can I call the `output$res` into `cat()` function in an rmarkdown file?

Comment: Solved: just need to call `result` instead of `res`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, you want to update the `numericInput` for factor when `delta` and/or `size` change.

```
observe({
    if(as.numeric(isolate(input$factor)) != 100){ 
        updateNumericInput(inputId = "factor", value = input$delta*input$size)
    }
})
```

You need to isolate `input$factor` otherwise it will always revert back to the `size*delta` every time `factor` is changed by a user.

Comment: Not completely. Working on the basic case, I would like to have as default value of the input `result`, the product `input$delta*input$size` . The code I posted is not working as it provides error in `value = input$delta*input$size`